# Is it acceptable that I plot a time-series figure with years increasing from right to left?

Tags: publications, graphics

I have a plot like this in my paper, but one of the co-authors says The x-axis is backward. I think as long as keeping all figures in the same style, it is ok. But I am not sure if there is really such a rule that years should increase from left to right? My field is environmental science.

[image: the figure in my paper]

Comment: @SolarMike: OP's current version of the image increases right to left, but she wants to know if there is a rule that it should go left to right instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge reviewer seems to think so...

Comment: Can you explain any benefit of doing it this way increasing right to left?

Comment: .tsael ta ,lanoitnevnocnu s'tI

Comment: Do you think it would be confusing to have the y-axis go from 100% at the bottom to 0% at the top?

Comment: You could change the label of the X axis from years to "years ago". However, that's generally only reasonable in fields like like paleontology and geology, where the units are thousands or millions of years. When you're dealing with individual years, making it relative to "now" changes the meaning as the paper gets old.

Comment: Could you clarify why you think the years should be in descending order like that? Doing so might elicit an answer that more directly addresses your particular situation.

Comment: If I saw a chart like this, my first instinct would be to assume that left is past and right is present/future, and once I got around to reading the year numbers, my next instinct would be to assume that you're trying to trick people.

Comment: One more thing you might consider - change the X axis labels to multiples of 10.  It's just weird having axis labels that all end with 2 or 7.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, if she only has data at 5 year intervals ending with in 2 and 7, she really doesn't have a choice.

Comment: @CramerTV The data seem to vary considerably more rapidly than at 5-year intervals.

Comment: @CramerTV the graph above appears to have data for every year.  But even if she did only have data from years ending in 2 or 7, she could still label the axis with multiples of 10, in which case the data points would fall BETWEEN the tick marks on the axis, rather than directly above them.

Comment: @JMac There is a long tradition of y axes going top to bottom in various fields. For instance, the coordinates on the computer screen you are looking at (computer graphics).

Comment: @Barmar: this is a good idea, but the numbers should be relative then (from 0 to 117 in OP's case). There would be no confusion there, but as you rightly mention the paper may get stale quickly (or at least the graphs)

Comment: In geology, I see both. Increasing age, or decreasing age (=time). Just be clear and label the axis (as you do!).

Comment: "With increasing age, this happens..." can make it more logical to plot years as in your example.

Comment: In which language is the paper written? Maybe in RTL languages charts are plotted RTL too?

Comment: @Bakuriu another user posted this as a comment on one of the answers *"In a right to left language, Cartesian coordinates are the same. x goes up from left to right."*

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The "rule" is that you should create figures that make it easy for readers to understand what you are showing. That's because we use figures to *convey* information. So, if your choice of axis is confusing readers, then you've violated the rule. Looking at your figure, I find it confusing, and several of the others here appear to have had the same reaction.

So yes, in this sense, there is a "rule" that years should increase left-to-right unless you have a very specific reason to it the other way around, and that reason is to make something easier to understand -- for example, if you were talking about what someone would experience who is traveling *backward in time*.

Comment: Perhaps if this were the year of birth, and you're looking at something that correlates to the age of the person.  But then it should be labeled by age (ascending) not birth year (descending).

Answer (score 118):

I think readers will be strongly expecting that time increases from left to right in a graph.  It's probably not a "rule" that you'll find written down anywhere, but it's certainly the overwhelmingly common practice. Having time go from right to left will very likely confuse your readers, and I don't think it should be done unless there is a very strong reason for it.

Comment: In a right to left language, Cartesian coordinates are the same. x goes up from left to right.

Comment: @QuoraFeans: Thanks!

Comment: @QuoraFeans That seems to be typically true for plotting on a Cartesian X-Y scale, though it isn't always true that the direction for time is the same for all types of charts and data. For example, my Hebrew-speaking colleagues have their (Gregorian) calendars organized such that time travels from right to left. At https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72562/is-the-mental-model-of-time-advancing-to-the-right-in-charts-globally-accepted one answer mentions that in Arabic, charts with a time axis can be RTL (though I see contradictions elsewhere).

Comment: @BryanKrause I've seen diagrams on placards in Israel where time was indeed right-to-left. Which, not being a Hebrew speaker myself, was confusing at first.

Answer (score 41):

As others have already pointed out: The *convention* is that the numbers should increase from left to right. And even though it's not really a *rule*, but only a *convention*, it is **so** common that any deviation might be hard to justifiy.

---

However, it **might** be the case that you're just using inappropriate labels. You mentioned that your field is environmental science, but did not exactly say what the graph shows. For example, if your graph shows information about something like "How much of a certain substance that was emitted in year X can still be detected today", then the order might make sense. But then, the labels should be "The number of years that have passed", turning the *absolute* years into a *duration*, then being properly ordered:

```
^
|
|
+-------|----------------|------------...-----------------|----------->
  after 1 year    after 10 years      ...          after ~100 years
  (from 2017)      (from 2007)                      (from 1917)
```

(That's only a wild guess, based on wondering why you chose the "wrong" direction in the first place - but you might think about it...)

Comment: actually, you had it all guessed right, amazing.... but I think I will just go with the others, and change my figures to the conventional style....thank you so much!

Comment: Carbon dating springs to mind, anything with a half life, or of epoch scale, and especially a log scale *back* to a cosmological event. Estimation of the historical distance to the moon. These have been cases.

Answer (score 12):

It is most common to increase chronologically from left to right any time you plot a timeseries along an x-axis, so that would be the standard unless you have a good reason not to do it that way. You are certainly allowed to do it differently - but you should have a good reason.

If you didn't do it that way a reader will tend to assume there must be some specific reason you chose to do it in a non-standard way. Alternatively, they will assume this must be done in the usual way so many readers will initially interpret it as if it was done in the usual way.

For your example image, even though I knew to pay attention to the x-axis, I initially thought there was a decrease in whatever you were studying over time. It took me a few extra moments to go, "oh, right, its the other way around, so I have to flip the trend...so it's actually been increasing over time, yes?"

One way to think of it is: readers are accustomed to being right-ward facing, wondering what comes next in the series. If you were trying to estimate what the past must have been like, based on more recent times, then it makes sense to start with the most recent time period on the left. If you are trying to imagine how things will be in the future, it makes more sense to start with the oldest time period and work towards the future on the right of the scale.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that axes usually can be thought of a having an origin at 0 and extend from there in negative or positive directions. Normally on a horizontal axis the positive direction is to the right and negative is to the left.  So moving from left to right moves to higher numbers. Of course time series plots don't usually show year 0, but you might want to think about where the origin (x=0) would be on your graph.   It's true that this is really just a convention and probably one enforced by people who are used to left to right languages (not to mention people who think maps should have north at the top).

Comment: This is the right answer.  Maybe people who grow up with RTL languages think that positive numbers increment from RTL, but people who grow up with a left-to-right language definitely think that numbers increment to the right.

Comment: Would you explain what _maps having north at the top_ is supposed to have to do with this?

Comment: Having maps with north at the top, east to the right is a convention many people are used to, but it's arbitrary.  That's why people notice it and are sometimes confused when maps are oriented in other ways, i.e. with south at the top.  So it's the same issue as having your axes go right to left (and up meaning higher number on the y axis).

Comment: @Elin As I wrote in another comment, numbers going up in the y axis are much less universal as a convention. For instance, computer screen coordinates go top to bottom, and so do row indices in a matrix.

Comment: Yes those are good examples,  although I would say that indices in a matrix  are not representing a number line so they aren't axes (although sometimes people use them that way, probably usually as the x axis).

Comment: Just saying: 1H and 13C-NMR spectroscopy orient the increasing scale about «chemical shift» from the right to the left, as chemists equally do about locating absorption bands by wavenumbers in infrared / IR spectroscopy (left: high number, right lower number).  The convention «left = low, right = high number» then is typically followed in mass spectrometry as well as in Raman and UV-Vis spectroscopy even if for the two later the colleagues from physics sometimes disagree, too.

Answer (score 6):

Backwards graphs are fairly common in some circles:
[image]
[Source](https://www.geocraft.com/WVFossils/last_400k_yrs.html)

Answer (score 5):

> Is it acceptable?

If the paper is written in a right-to-left language - then yes, but then - please also place the Y axis labels on the *right* side of the figure.

Otherwise, it's only appropriate if:

- you have a reason to plot your figures like this, and
- you clearly indicate, graphically, the direction of progression along the X axis, with text or graphics or both, e.g. 
  [image] 
  (ugly PNG image, but you catch my drift); and it wouldn't hurt to switch the Y-axis labels to the right *right* in this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

A graph axis is a (segment of a) [number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_line).  Numbers increase to the right on a number line.  Not all variables are numerical and therefore not all variables support axes: categorical variables are a prominent example.

The *first* thing readers notice about your graph (even before meaningfully looking at it) is that there is a decreasing trend.  Do you intend to convey that some quantity is decreasing?  If so, then this graph conveys your intent.

Only after carefully inspecting the horizontal axis does a reader discover that you have a non-numerical independent variable (because your labels are not in number line order).  Do you intend to treat years as non-numerical data?  If so, then this graph conveys your intent.